# Ember localstorage adapter has different data when I refresh

Tags: ember.js, local-storage, ember-data

I'm relatively new to Ember and have been struggling to build a simple CRUD app for learning purposes. I'm using localstorage-adapter to mock the backend. I'm having a horribly bad time debugging because Ember Inspector shows different data on different pages.

Right now I have full CRUD functionality except for updating. Say I create a new Song (S1) that's a part of an album (A1). I can change S1 to belong to another album (A2), and that saves and persists in local storage even if I refresh.

Now, if I decide I want to change S1's album back to A1, it'll save and display on the show page, but if I refresh, the album reverts to A2. If I go to the edit page, S1's album is listed as A2. If I refresh on the edit page, it changes to A1, but even if I click save it'll show A1 on the show page but if I refresh or go back to edit it goes back to A2... I find this especially weird because it did save properly (and persisted with page reloading) on the initial edit attempt. It's subsequent edit attempts that it doesn't save properly.

A song has a title and belongs to an album.

Songs Controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    updateValue(value) {
      this.set('model.song.newAlbum', value)
    },
    updateSong(model) {
      this.store.findRecord('song', model.get('id'))
        .then(song => {
          if (song.get('newAlbum')) {
            this.store.findRecord('album', song.get('newAlbum'))
              .then(album => {
                song.set('album', album);
                album.save();
              })
          }
        song.save();
      })
      .then(() => this.transitionToRoute('songs.show', model.get('id')));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: To further illustrate the problem: when I refresh on different pages, the data changes. If I go to my main page and empty cache + hard reload, the data looks correct. S1 belongs to A1. If I then navigate to S1's edit page or A2's show page, the data changes and S1 now belongs to A2.

This is causing a host of other issues with my app. For example, if I move things around and then delete, at some point, a certain page will break because it tries to fetch a record for data for something that doesn't exist (and it should no longer have a relationship with).

Comment: If you add an error handler to your save() calls with catch(), does it reveal more information? https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/#toc_promises

Comment: I added a catch to console.log the error, but nothing was logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure the data persists properly on the back end (which is the local storage in this project), you'll need to do a bit more management of the relationships.

You'll need to:

1. **Set the new album** as the song's album property - `song.set('album', newAlbum)`
2. **Save the song's old album** if there was one to remove the song from `oldAlbum.songs`
3. **Save the song**: persist the `song.album` property to the back end
4. **Save the song's new album**: persist the updated `newAlbum.songs` to the back end

In addition, I've used [RSVP Hash to return multiple models](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_multiple-models) so you don't have to fetch the song data object in your function (it's resolved and passed in to the model for you)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      song: this.store.findRecord('song', params.song_id),
      albums: this.store.findAll('album')
    })
  },
  actions: {
    updateSong(song) {
      if (song.get('newAlbum')) {
        //  Get the current album's Ember object as 'oldAlbum'
        song.get('album').then((oldAlbum) => {
          // Then get the new album's Ember object as 'newAlbum'
          this.store.findRecord('album', song.get('newAlbum')).then(newAlbum => {
            // Set the song's album to the new album
            song.set('album', newAlbum);
            if (oldAlbum) {
              // Save the old album if it exists
              oldAlbum.save();
            }
            // Save the new album
            newAlbum.save();
            // Save the song
            song.save().then(() => {
              // Then transition to new route
              this.transitionTo('songs.show', song.get('id'))
            })
          })
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Finally, just a heads up that the push that sets up your initial entities in your routes/application.js only pushes to the cache and not the local storage. With those there, you will always see Go Go Go associated with What Is Life -- don't let it throw you off.

Also, remember you can cut and paste the local storage contents out of your developer tools to help debug what's in there vs. the Ember cache.

Comment: When I changed my function to look like yours and try to make an edit, I get an error that says "Error: Assertion Failed: The route ag4g9 was not found", where ag4g9 is the id of the song I'm editing. For some reason, the artist was deleted? It still seems to exist in local storage, but not in Data in Ember Inspector (depending on the page). Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: That sounds to me like it could be a problem with the route transition but it's hard to say what without seeing more code or running a working minimal example. Any chance you can post your project on github?

Comment: Yeah of course. I was actually working on this as a coding challenge, and have since submitted it. That said, the fact that it doesn't work properly drives me nuts and I'd still like to figure out what I was doing wrong for my own knowledge.

https://github.com/amygbui/ember

Comment: Cool thanks for posting the github link! I was able to get the project running and find the problem. In sum, we need to save the album models in addition to the song to persist their "songs" properties and keep everything in sync.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick and makes a lot of sense :D